# Windows TCP socket, writing and reading full

Tags: sockets, tcp, winsock

We have a situation where client writes faster than the server can read, say every 1 second or less a client writes to a server making the tcp socket buffer full and therefore disconnects.

How to handle this sort of situation?
Is there a way to check tcp socket buffer from client side before writing and waits until buffer is freed and can send again?

Here is a sample pseudo code to easily reproduce the issue

Server

```
socket = create server Socket at port 7777;
socket->Accept(); //wait for just 1 connection

while(true)
{
   // just do nothing and let the client fill the buffe
}
```

Client

```
socket = connect to localhost 7777
while(true)
{
    socket->write("hello from test");
}
```

this will loop until write buffer is full, and it will hang up, and will disconnects with win socket error 10057.

Comment: "Therefore disconnects": why would it disconnect? Could you edit your question to include the code that does this?

Comment: the reproduction is simple, I can reproduce it in a bare minimum approach
in one side you have a server, accepts connection, then enters the reading thread, but instead of reading inside a thread (just for replication) do nothing, just fill in the buffer.

the test client application will just connects to the server, and publish a message say "Hello from test" with 0 delay, it will succeed until some number (in my test its 46778 message), since the server is not reading any it will fill. and sending the 46779th message will block and disconnects with error 10057.

Comment: Did you set a timeout?  Because normally the sender will just keep waiting until the receiver reads some data.  Make a [mcve] and not just snippets.

Comment: So you're using the sending socket in blocking mode? About how long does it take from the last time write starts blocking, to when the error occurs?

Comment: @user2300947 "*since the server is not reading any it will fill [the buffer]. and sending the 46779th message will block and disconnects with error 10057*" - disconnecting on a full buffer is not how TCP sockets behave by default, the sender will simply block waiting for the buffer to clear space. TCP has built-in flow control to regulate this. So there has to be something else going on to cause error 10057. That is not an error that `send()` would return under normal conditions if the sender has not closed its socket yet. Please don't show "pseudo code", show "actual" code instead.

Comment: @user2300947 "*Is there a way to check tcp socket buffer from client side before writing and waits until buffer is freed and can send again?*" - yes, use `select()` or equivalent to wait for the socket to be in a writable state before sending. This is best when coupled with putting the socket in non-blocking mode.